# How to properly use Lombok @Data with interfaces

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, lombok

I'm using quite a bit of native queries in my spring book application since Hibernate won't allow me to write Join queries using Join Tables that are not mapped. I came across this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/spring-data-jpa-projection-support-for-native-queries-a13cd88ec166) which helped me to project Native Queries into DTOs beautifully. As mentioned in the article I'm using a DTO interface with an @Data (Lombok) annotation. It worked like a charm while I was running it locally inside eclipse via "Run as Spring Boot Application". But when I'm trying to `mvn package` it in order to deploy the JAR, I'm getting a compilation error, stating

`myDTO.java:[8,1] @Data is only supported on a class.`

I don't understand how it works so well while I'm running it in eclipse and maven gives me a compilation error.

Edit: It works in the Java 8 (used in eclipse) and throws a compilation error in Java 11 (Global path version).

Comment: I'd go and try to find differences in the classpath or configuration when running with mvn or eclipse.

Comment: How did you configure Lombok in your pom?

Comment: @D.Lawrence I have not made any additional configuration for Lombok in my pom. Just added the dependency

Comment: @ldz Thanks for the pointer. It seems that I am using the Java SE 1.8 inside JDK11 in Eclipse while the default path uses JDK 11 directly.

Comment: You cant add @Data on interfaces because their attributes are implicit public static final.

Comment: @Guilherme What you say makes sense, but if that's the reason, I'm not able to relate to how it works in Java 8. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm using java 8, and it generates a compiler error when I put @Data on interfaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You found a lombok 'bug', in that the eclipse variant should also have generated that error instead of doing nothing. Because.. it's doing nothing.

The reason the appropriate response is that error is because `@Data` on an interface makes no sense. `@Data` does 4 things. Before I enumerate them, just to be clear, interfaces **cannot have (non-static) fields**. You can write it, but java will silently upgrade them to `public static final`.

`@Data`:

- Makes a constructor. (Not legal to do to an interface, so, it can't do that).
- Makes a getter and setter for each non-static field. (There can't be any, in an interface, so this does nothing).
- It makes a `toString` that prints the type, and each non-static field (There CAN be one, even with an impl using the `default` feature, but all it would do is print the type's name; not a very useful `toString`!)
- It makes an `equals` and `hashCode` impl (Here too it can exist, but all it would do is return a constant value for `hashcode` and return a convoluted mess for `equals` and `canEqual` which doesn't make much sense as the point is to compare the non-static fields and there aren't any). None of this makes any sense because any classes that implement this interface are effectively forced into overriding these methods for them to work anyway, at which point these implementations will not be used.

I think you're a bit confused, or at least, *I* am, so, let's take a step back and talk about what problem you're trying to solve / what you think would be happening if you put `@Data` on an interface.

NB: Java11 vs. Java8 difference is a red herring; that's not the problem here.
NB2: Disclaimer - I'm a core maintainer of project lombok.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can write the interface proper and then use @Data on the implementing class, it works well.

Comment: Is there any way to connect interface and implementation VIA lombok and not to write manually setters and getters in interface?

Comment: @IgnatGalkin There is not.

Comment: @rzwitserloot thank you for answer. Don't you consider it like a useful feature to implement? For people like me that are using coding by intention approach it might be really helpful.

Comment: @IgnatGalkin No. An interface for a property container is weird.

Comment: Can't Lombok solve this like Immutables by generating something like `MutablePerson` as an implementation of `@Data interface Person`?

Comment: @aioobe that would be pointless. Just write `class MutablePerson` and stick `@Data` on that. If you want to 'extract' an interface out of that contains a subset, then - which subset? "Everything except auto-generated setters" - that seems weird to me. Who says those other methods don't also mutate? Who guards against this? If you say: No, those don't exist, Person is _just_ a property container - then, why do you want an interface like this? It doesn't strike me as common boilerplate. Explain the use case.

Comment: To be clear, 'immutables' is just an annotation processor (unlike lombok which is a compiler plugin), so it has you go through the rigamarole of writing an interface because _it has to_ - that `@MutablesThingie interface Person` is a template definition so immutables knows what to generate. It's less convenient, requires full builds, and so on.

Comment: My use case was that I had both a `class Cat implements Animal` and a `class Dog implements Animal`, and figured I wouldn't have valid Java code if I let Lombok generate a bunch of `Animal` methods for me.

Your second comment was precisely what I needed to hear. I assume that it _will_ work. Lombok as a compiler plugin will fulfill the interface requirements before any compile errors will be generated, right?

Comment: @aioobe Yup :) that'll work.